# subplot into splitted screen in R

Tags: r, plot, par

I would like to add a subplot to a plot in a splitted screen in R.
An intuitive and simple way would be:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(15:1)
par(new=T,fig=c(0.5,1,0.5,1))
plot(1:15)
```

I want the second plot (1:15) in the upperright corner of the first (15:1) and the same for five further plots. but unfortunately the fig-values are taken for the whole margin and not only for the first screen out of the 6.

what I also tried already:
split with

```
layout(matrix(1:6,2))
split.screen(6) # and fill the screens with a loop
```

As the real plots are quite complex, I also stored them with recordPlot and tried to fill the 6 part-screens with replayPlot. I also used subplot() (from package TeachingDemos) instead of the par(fig()) argument.

The result is the same all the time - the subplot is in the upperright of the whole margin.

Did anyone solve this problem or knows another way to try? There are few similar questions here, and none of them were answered... But it would be nice if this were possible ;-)

Thanks

Comment: Instead of setting `par(fig)`, you need to set `par(plt)`.

Comment: Yeah! It still needs a little bit of creativity, but it works now! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Great, glad that worked out!